# Changing the value of an attribute and saving it using ReactiveMongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa, spring-webflux

In a mongok script I want to update the value of an attribute and save the change, in the project I currently only have a ReactiveMongoRepository

I'm sure that I'm missing something stupid but I can't figure it out

Here are my simplified classes

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface CalendarMongoRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<CalendarMongo, CalendarMongoId> {
    //Some methods not used here
}
```

POJO :

```
@Document("calendars")
public class CalendarMongo {

    @Id
    private CalendarMongoId id;

    private String calendar;

    public String getCalendar() {
        return calendar;
    }

    public CalendarMongo setCalendar(String calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
        return this;
    }

    //Other getters setters and other attributes

}
```

POJO ID :

```
public class CalendarMongoId {

    @Indexed(name = "branchCode_index")
    private BranchEnum branchCode;

    //Getters setters and other attributes
}
```

Mongok Script :

```
@Slf4j
@ChangeUnit(id = "SetupAttribute", order = "7", author = "mongock")
public class DatabaseChangeV007SetupAttribute {

    private final CalendarMongoRepository calendarMongoRepository;

    public DatabaseChangeV007SetupFieldType(CalendarMongoRepository calendarMongoRepository) {
        this.calendarMongoRepository = calendarMongoRepository;
    }

    @Execution
    public void migrationMethod() {
        calendarMongoRepository.findAll()
                           .map(calendarMongo -> calendarMongo.setCalendar("AA"))
                           .map(calendarMongoRepository::save);

    }

    @RollbackExecution
    public void rollback() {
        log.error("Rollback invoked");
    }

}
```

When I launch my project this script just does nothing, I do not see the change in my database. I'm sure the problem is not the structure of the script because of other tests.

I tried to use doOnNext but it's not the way to do.

I tried to use flatMap but I didn't manage to make it work either.

Do you have an idea ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: you forgot to subscribe()

Comment: If I .suscribe() after the map I get a reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.mongock.driver.api.lock.LockCheckException

Comment: check this https://docs.mongock.io/v5/driver/mongodb-reactive/index.html